# Merging Map streams using Java 8 Lambda Expression

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have two maps `m1` and `m2` of type `Map<Integer, String>`, which has to be merged into a single map
`Map<Integer, List<String>>`, where values of same keys in both the maps are collected into a List and put into a new Map.

Solution based on what I explored:

```java
Map<Integer, List<String>> collated =
        Stream.concat(m1.entrySet().stream(), m2.entrySet().stream()).collect(
                Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                        Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> {
                            List<String> merged = new ArrayList<String>(a);
                            merged.addAll(b);
                            return merged;
                        }));
```

But, this solution expects source `List` to be `Map<Integer, List<String>>` as the merge function in toMap expects operands and result to be of the same type.

I don't want to change the source collection. Please provide your inputs on achieving this using lambda expression.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't test it right now, but I think all you need it to change the mapping of the value from `Entry::getValue` to a List that contains that value :

```java
Map<Integer, List<String>> collated =
        Stream.concat(m1.entrySet().stream(), m2.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                        e -> {
                            List<String> v = new ArrayList<String>();
                            v.add(e.getValue());
                            return v;
                        },
                        (a, b) -> {
                            List<String> merged = new ArrayList<String>(a);
                            merged.addAll(b);
                            return merged;
                        }));
```

EDIT: The idea was correct. The syntax wasn't. Current syntax works, though a bit ugly. There must be a shorter way to write it.

You can also replace `e -> {..}` with `e -> new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{e.getValue()}))`.

or with `e -> Stream.of(e.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Or you can do it with `groupingBy` :

```java
Map<Integer, List<String>> collated =
        Stream.concat(m1.entrySet().stream(), m2.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 22):

That's a job for [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)collector:

```
Stream.of(m1,m2)
        .flatMap(m->m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())
        ));
```

Answer (score 3):

Misha's solution is the best if you want pure Java-8 solution. If you don't mind using third-party libraries, it would be a little shorter using my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex).

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = StreamEx.of(m1, m2)
        .flatMapToEntry(Function.identity())
        .grouping();
```

Internally it's the same as in Misha's solution, just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a great opportunity to use Guava's [`Multimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

```
ListMultimap<Integer, String> collated = ArrayListMultimap.create();
collated.putAll(Multimaps.forMap(m1));
collated.putAll(Multimaps.forMap(m2));
```

And if you really need a `Map<Integer, List<String>>`:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> mapCollated = Multimaps.asMap(collated);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method with three parameters for clarity.

```java
Map<Integer, String> m1 = Map.of(1, "A", 2, "B");
Map<Integer, String> m2 = Map.of(1, "C", 2, "D");
```

```java
// two maps into one
Map<Integer, List<String>> m3 = Stream
        .of(m1.entrySet(), m2.entrySet())
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                // key - Integer
                e -> e.getKey(),
                // value - List<String>
                e -> List.of(e.getValue()),
                // mergeFunction - two lists into one
                (list1, list2) -> {
                    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list.addAll(list1);
                    list.addAll(list2);
                    return list;
                }));
```

```java
// output
System.out.println(m3); // {1=[A, C], 2=[B, D]}
```